# Exporting a csv file to remote server using SFTP in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, sftp

I am working on an `ssis` package which gets data from `SQL data source` and exports it to a `csv` file which in turn should be copied to different folders on remote server using `SFTP`

I have the first two steps completed but I am wondering how I can `SFTP` the same file into more than one folder on same remote server.

Do I have to write a different package to handle the file export to different folders or can it be done on the same package.

Please note that number of folders that this file should be copied to varies from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dataflow task in combination with SFTP task and precedence constraints to accomplish this.

[image]

You will need to configure the path variables also for the separate destinations on the SFTP server.

Once the first SFTP task completes, the next Dataflow task and SFTP transfer will begin.

[image]

The answer is you can do do it in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a for each loop container with multiple **copy** to SFTP actions within it and set the file name as an expression to be populated within the FEL for each SFTP action?